# using dig to search for MX hostnames and their ip v4 and v6

Tags: php, dns, ipv6, ipv4, dig

the code below used php functions to get me MX hostnames and their just ip version 4:

```
    $results = dns_get_record($domain, DNS_MX);

    foreach ($results as $res) {
        $hostip = gethostbyname($res['target']);
    }
```

i googled a lot about 'dig' and found "dig -t MX redhat.com +noall +answer" but it returns just the MX hostnames without their IPV4 and IPV6.
Is there a way to get the job done using "dig" or PHP Functions?

Answer (score 1):

The MX record contains [only hostnames, never IP addresses](https://serverfault.com/q/663112/126632).

If you want to look up the IP address of a hostname you received, you will need to perform another DNS lookup. It appears that your code is already doing this (and then throwing away some of the results, which is a bug). But unless you intend to do something with the IP address *other than open a connection*, then you should probably just use the hostname.